# Eclipse IDE plugin for my development

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I am using Eclipse Juno IDE.
When I change my code, I have to redeploy my project. I think it takes a long time. So
can you tell me, are there any plugins that allow me to avoid redployment?

Comment: Re-deploy to what? :) And what do you mean by no need to redeploy? Run locally instead of uploading the site, or have it deployed automatically?

Comment: @Joachim Isaksson 
sorry for my english :(

Comment: @Iloveseventeen Butnotsixt
Provided you are talking about a web application as i recall the WTP plugin has a (by default ON) feature called "deploy on save" or something similar. As the name states if you change a JSP file it will be 'deployed' to the container.

Comment: @dave00 So WTP plugin already included in eclipse? Thanks for ur answer.

Comment: @Iloveseventeen Butnotsixt
It depends on which setup you've downloaded. If you went with the EE version you should have it i think. If not it's no issue to add it through the "Install New Software" menu.

Comment: @dave00  from Help>Install New Software .Am i right?

Comment: Correct. That is what you are looking for.